# How to disable "Mini Call View" feature in Google's latest Phone app?

Tags: calls, google-apps, phone-app

The latest version of [Google's Phone (v 23)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer&hl=en_US) app has a feature called "Mini Call View" in which when you answer a call it won't open the phone dialer. Instead, there is a notification in the notification bar and if you expand the notification bar you will see an on-going call and a button to hang up and another button to start speaker phone.

I don't like this feature and I want to disable it. I want the full phone dialer to open up when answering  a call.

Does anyone know how to disable Mini Call View in Google's Phone app? Or at the very least does anyone know how to open the phone dial pad by default when answering a call?

Comment: This app isn't available in my country. Anyway try installing an [activity shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher) or any other such app and check if  the phone app exposes an activity to display the dial pad. If it does, you can make a shortcut of that on your homescreen and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this mini call view primarily happens when you have Do Not Disturb enabled. If you disable, the regular Phone app view should appear when you answer a call. Same with if you add an exception to your Do Not Disturb list and that person calls.

I was able to fix my issue by adding the particular contact to my Do Not Disturb exception list.

Comment: If I'm not misremembering, this may also happen on full-screen apps/games.